# Why does my React app compilation take a long time or get stuck?

Tags: reactjs

I have problem with compiling in ReactJS. I define a few images in array. So far, all this is working properly. However, the source of the image (path) is still the same, but the images are overwritten in the folder. But when that happens - one image is overwritten - it always gets stuck with the message "`compiling`" in the console and I have to restart `npm start`.

How can I resolve this? Or if you have another solution how to solve this whole case?

```
const SAMPLE_IMG = [
{
    id: 1,
    name: "op4",
    path: require("./img/op4.png"),
    date: Date.now(),
},
{
    id: 2,
    name: "op5",
    path: require("./img/op5.png"),
    date: Date.now(),
}
];
```

Then i images render:

```
    {images.map((item) => {
        return (
            <img
                key={item.id}
                src={`${item.path}?${item.date}`}
            ></img>
        );
    })}
```

Comment: Is there something different about that image? Is it extremely large or of another type?

Comment: @isherwood Just that it is not, the pictures are practically identical only with a different time.

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm seeing with the image source markup. Can you revise to clarify?

Comment: @isherwood Do you think this: {`${item.path}?${item.date}`} ?  It is due to unique identifier for image and then i check if any different there and re-render component.